# Why is my CSS :hover @keyframes animation not working?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-animations

I am a newbie. Why is this code not working?
I want to make the bird fly.

My html:

```
<img src="http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105046436/tw.png" />
<br>
<div class="twitter-bird"></div>
```

My CSS:

```
.twitter-bird {
    background-image: url(http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105046436/tw.png);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 38px;
    width: 37.5px;
}

.twitter-bird:hover {
    animation: fly 0.2s steps(3) 0 infinite;
}

@keyframes fly {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: -112.5px 0; }
}
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6qHMG/

What I want:

I want to change the background position of the image.

What happens:

Image position does not change on hover.

EDIT:
I think the background image position does not change properly. The background-position doesn't seem to change. How do I set `background-position:` in `@keyframes fly` ?

Comment: Well, what does it do? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Comment: Updated, I missed that line.

Comment: Yes, please let us know if it gives you free waffles, if so, I'll most definitely attempt to recreate this "bug"

Comment: @Doorknob, help please

Comment: @sinhayash: Stack Overflow isn't a help site. It's a question and answer site. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free "fix my code for me please thanks" site. I and all of the other users here answer questions because we volunteer to, and if you don't show any effort to fix your problem then we won't either.

Comment: Yes, @PaulD.Waite, why is it not working?

Comment: Again, we aren't free code fixing support people! Please read the link that Paul gave you.

Comment: So hints please, I'll try to solve it...

Comment: @sinhayash: I don't think you  quite understand what I was trying to say.

Comment: @sinhayash: I think I edited the link into my comment after posting, so you might have missed it. Here it is again, sorry about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry about my vague question, but really I'm unable to sort why is it not working...May I get some help please

Comment: No, you will not get an answer until you improve your question! You don't seem to be understanding what we're saying...

Comment: @sinhayash: nope. You need to improve your question first. You're not doing too badly: you've told us what steps you've taken, and you've told us what you expect to happen. But you haven't told us what actually happens. Without seeing that extra bit of effort into your question, I don't fancy answering it. (That's just me, of course.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I have updated the question. Any other mistake which I am overlooking?
Apologies, I am a newbie.

Comment: @sinhayash: cool, much better, and no worries. I reckon the title could be more descriptive, but that's just a wording issue.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, Thanks now I know how to ask questions here. Thanks a lot

Comment: @sinhayash: you're very welcome. Glad you got an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here it is:

u have to add vendor prefixes

```
.twitter-bird {
    height: 38px;
    width: 37.5px;
    background-image: url("http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105046436/tw.png");
}

.twitter-bird:hover { 
    -webkit-animation: fly .4s steps(3) infinite;
       -moz-animation: fly .4s steps(3) infinite;
        -ms-animation: fly .4s steps(3) infinite;
         -o-animation: fly .4s steps(3) infinite;
            animation: fly .4s steps(3) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fly {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -112.5px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fly {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -112.5px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes fly {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -112.5px; }
}

@-o-keyframes fly {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -112.5px; }
}

@keyframes fly {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -112.5px; }
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6qHMG/4/

Comment: Vendor prefix is required for chrome, safari and opera. ie and firefox, support standard keyword.